# swedish support on UIButton and UILabel

Tags: iphone

I need to create app that supports Swedish and English languages. Please help me to add Swedish support on UILabel and UIButton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can internationalize your app. 
We found [this](http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/iphone-applications-localization-guide/) guide very useful when adding support for multiple languages
Apple has [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html) to say about supporting multiple languages